# Query in view - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I decided to add some stats of my app in my footer so I did what I thought that was the easier, make queries in my view.

**VIEW**

```
<div>    
<h4>Quelques chiffres clés.</h4>
      Nombre total des idées: <%= Idee.all.count %> 
      <br/>Nombre total des idées publiées:<%= Idee.where(statut_id: 1).count %> 
      <br/>Nombre total des idées en cours de traitement:<%= Idee.where(statut_id: 3).count %>
      <br/>Nombre total des idées mises en place:<%= Idee.where(statut_id: 2).count %>
    </div>
```

But after all I don't think it's the best way to do this, so there is a better way to do this ? In my model ? controller ?

Comment: Use controller to query your DB and pass the value to your view.

Comment: You never query directly from a view, You query on the controller side and then pass it to the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Footer is available for each and every view, so it would be better to add the code in application controller, its not recommended to add queries in the view, so in your application controller

```
before_filter :idee_counter

def idee_counter
  idee = Idee.select(:id, :statut_id)
  @total_count = idee.size
  @total_stat_1 = idee.where(statut_id: 1).size
  @total_stat_3 = idee.where(statut_id: 3).size
  @total_stat_2 = idee.where(statut_id: 2).size  
end
```

Then in view

```
<div>    
  <h4>Quelques chiffres clés.</h4>
  Nombre total des idées: <%= @total_count %> 
  <br/>Nombre total des idées publiées:<%= @total_stat_1 %> 
  <br/>Nombre total des idées en cours de traitement:<%= @total_stat_3 %>
  <br/>Nombre total des idées mises en place:<%= @total_stat_2 %>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes thank you ! I already tried this but I had forgotten the "before_filter" but now it's working

Answer (score 0):

In your controller:

```
@idees = Idee.all
```

In your view:

```
<div>    
  <h4>Quelques chiffres clés.</h4>
  Nombre total des idées: <%= @idees.count %> 
  <br/>Nombre total des idées publiées:<%= @idees.where(statut_id: 1).count %> 
  <br/>Nombre total des idées en cours de traitement:<%= @idees.where(statut_id: 3).count %>
  <br/>Nombre total des idées mises en place:<%= @idees.where(statut_id: 2).count %>
</div>
```